# upload image on mobile device for drupal site

Tags: drupal, media

I have a drupal site with the media module installed. When I click 'select media' and try to upload an image on a mobile device I get a blank box instead of the popup box with the upload option. I've checked the console and there are no error. How do I debug this and make it work on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You can add images to Drupal, but mobile devices don't allow you to upload any photos to image fields. (Android allows it as I remember.)

HTML5 allows this, but sadly that's mostly a no go with Drupal 7 at the moment. However, it turns out the fix is nice and easy via the [HTML Media Capture](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/camera/) method. Add the following snippet of jQuery, so it runs when pages load:

```
$('div.image-widget-data input[type="file"]').each(function(idx, item) {
   $(item).attr('accept', 'image/*;capture=camera');
});
```

That will look for  items inside image widgets and add the *accept* attribute This then tells mobile devices they can upload image data and are allowed to grab that from their on-board camera.

To make that a spot simpler on Drupal, you can grab the [Image Mobile Camera](http://drupal.org/sandbox/cafuego/1980210) module from its [sandbox](http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/cafuego/1980210.git) on Drupal.org.

Now hit your blog via your tablet or phone (using a browser that supports this - Chrome is fine) and try it out.

Hope that helps

Comment: where should I put this code? Which file? I don't have the file image_mobile_camera.module